# Why does 'Cracking The Coding Interview' advices to create an array chars[128]?

Tags: java, unicode, ascii

As far as I know, there are 65,535 chars in the Java language.
Meanwhile, Unicode 11.0, contains a repertoire of 137,439 signs.
I'm reading Cracking The Coding Interview and can't understand the internals of the present solution.

**Why does the book advice to create an array chars[128] in a case if String represents Unicode if there can be 137,439 Unicode signs?**

I'm not familiar with encoding, could you explain me it in details?

**Is Unique: Implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters. What if you cannot use additional data structures?**

*SOLUTION*

You should first ask your interviewer if the string is an ASCII string or a Unicode string. Asking this question
will show an eye for detail and a solid foundation in computer science. We'll assume for simplicity the character
set is ASCII. If this assumption is not valid, we would need to increase the storage size.
One solution is to create an array of boolean values, where the flag at index i indicates whether character
i in the alphabet is contained in the string. The second time you see this character you can immediately
return false.
We can also immediately return false if the string length exceeds the number of unique characters in the
alphabet. After all, you can't form a string of 280 unique characters out of a 128-character alphabet.
I It's also okay to assume 256 characters. This would be the case in extended ASCII. You should
clarify your assumptions with your interviewer.
The code below implements this algorithm.

```
boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
   if (str.length() > 128) return false;
   boolean[] char_set = new boolean[128];
   for (int i= 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      int val= str.charAt(i);
      if (char_set[val]) {  //Already found this char in string
         return false;
      }
      char_set[val] = true;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: It says right there "We'll assume for simplicity the character set is ASCII"

Comment: ***After all, you can't form a string of 280 unique characters out of a 128-character alphabet*** You have a 128-character alphabet...

Comment: You should edit your question so that it makes more sense when reading it. Write the book and author's name and also make it so reader's know what is quoted from the book and what's written by you.

Comment: Unicode codepoints need a range of 21 bits. UTF-16 encodes those 21 bits as one or two 16-bit code units (`char`). Your learning aid is obscuring basic information from primary references. Your question represents good critical thinking.

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by the book advises the reader to ask if the characters are in Unicode or ASCII to demonstrate some insight.

However the writer proceeded with assuming ASCII is used which is 128 characters so this is why a 128 array size  is used.

It also mentions that extended-ASCII could be assumed which is 256 characters.  In this case a 256 size array should be used .

The writer also mentions that in case of Unicode the array size should be increased but does not really specify the size.

A clarification based on Tom Blodget's comment is that there is the implicit assumption in both the question and the answer that the String parameter 'str' of the function 'isUniqueChars' is given as input by e.g. reading a file.
The restrictions of ASCII, extended-ASCII etc apply to this input not to Java String itself. This is because all characters and strings in Java are UTF-16.

Comment: All characters and strings in Java are UTF-16. The keys are: Is there a performance need to identify a subset and is there a subset that is identifiable. For exercises, the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block is sometimes used, sometimes along with the C1 Controls and Latin 1 Supplement block. I don't think I've ever worked on a project that enjoyed such a limited set of characters.

Comment: This is absolutely true. What is not clarified above, is the assumption that the String parameter 'str' of the function 'isUniqueChars' is read by a file or other input. The restrictions of ASCII, extended-ASCII etc should apply to this input. Indeed it is not mentioned anywhere explicitly, so I will edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: But, most "Extended ASCII" character sets have some characters that don't map to the U+0000 to U+00FF range so the 256 element array won't work.

Comment: This is interesting. Indeed  if the characters of UTF-16 do not map in the range of the Extended ASCII the 256 array will throw an out of bounds exception .